# vertical space beneath last item across pages in a multicols environment

Tags: spacing, header-footer, lists, multicol

I am using the `multicols` environment to create a simple worksheet with exercises in two columns.  Everything works wonderfully, except if the exercises span multiple pages, the `multicols` environment justifies the last item on a page to the bottom of the page, leaving no room for the student to do the work.  I found an easy fix to this by simply making my bottom margin larger and removing my footer:

[image]

which came from this code:

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top=1.125in, bottom=2.125in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{16pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{MVCC Math 141 \\ Jaffary}
\fancyhead[R]{Practice Problems}
%\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
%\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
%\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Exercises}
\hrule
\medskip
Solve the following equations.
\medskip

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}\itemsep3.2cm
%   \\
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

I am looking for a better way to do this, and retain a footer.  The following image shows the problem I encountered:

[image]

which came from this code, where the bottom margin is the same as the top and there is a footer:

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top=1.125in, bottom=1.125in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{16pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{MVCC Math 141 \\ Jaffary}
\fancyhead[R]{Practice Problems}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\begin{document}

\section*{Exercises}
\hrule
\medskip
Solve the following equations.
\medskip

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}\itemsep3.5cm
%   \\
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
    \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
    \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
    \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem also occurs at ordinary page breaks, since the `itemsep` is descarded there.  One way to work around this is to insert space via `\vspace*`, which generally does not get discarded, however you need to be careful at the end of the list.  In the following I define a new environment `exer`, and a new length `\exerspace` for the separation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[reqno,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm}
\usepackage[top=1.125in, bottom=1.125in, left=0.75in, right=0.75in]{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{28pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{16pt}
\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{MVCC Math 141 \\ Jaffary}
\fancyhead[R]{Practice Problems}
\fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.1pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.1pt}

\newlength{\exerspace}
\setlength{\exerspace}{3.5cm plus 0.5cm}
\newenvironment{exer}{\begin{enumerate}\let\olditem\item%
    \def\item{\ifnum \value{enumi}>0\vspace*{\exerspace}\fi\olditem}%
}{\vspace*{\exerspace}\vspace{0pt}\end{enumerate}%
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Exercises}
\hrule
\medskip
Solve the following equations.
\medskip

\begin{multicols}{2}
  \begin{exer}
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
  \item $3 \cdot 2^{x} = 48$
  \item $3 \cdot \log_{2}(x) = 12$
  \item $3 \sqrt[4]{x} = 6$
\end{exer}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Note that I have set `\exerspace` to have a minimum size `3.5cm` together with some extra stretchability `plus 0.5cm`; this provides flexibility to space items out more evenly on the page.

Comment: Thank you!  I wasn't aware of this response until just now. Worked beautifully.